# Put a list in a column of data frame

Tags: r

I'm sorry for my english :)

I need to detect if there is a special character in an address (variable "no_trans", 1 : if there is one or several special character, else 0) and in the next column ("carac_no_trans") I need to put the list of the special character, so if there is several special character I need to see all in this column.

My code (liste_carac is the list of non-special character. I need to detect all characters not included in this list) :

```
new <- data_adresse %>% 
  group_by(e_street_name) %>% 
  mutate(
    no_trans = ifelse(
      length(
        setdiff(
          unlist(strsplit(e_street_name,"")),
          liste_carac
        )
      ) >= 1,
      1,
      0
    ),
    carac_no_trans = ifelse(
      length(
        as.list(
          setdiff(
            unlist(strsplit(e_street_name,"")),
            liste_carac
          )
        )
      ) >= 1,
      as.list(
        setdiff(
          unlist(strsplit(e_street_name,""))
          liste_carac
        ),
      ),
      "None"
    )
  )
```

But I see just the first special character and not all..

[image]

If you can help me :)

Have a good day !
Elise

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: You could use `paste` to combine all the special characters into one string.

Comment: I try to replace `as.list` by `paste` but I have the same issue @BertilBaron ..

Answer (score 0):

you can use `paste` with the parameter `collaps = ", "` to reduce the list into one single string like this

```
new <- data_adresse %>% 
  group_by(e_street_name) %>% 
  mutate(
    no_trans = ifelse(
      length(
        setdiff(
          unlist(strsplit(e_street_name,"")),
          liste_carac
        )
      ) >= 1,
      1,
      0
    ),
    carac_no_trans = ifelse(
      length(
        as.list(
          setdiff(
            unlist(strsplit(e_street_name,"")),
            liste_carac
          )
        )
      ) >= 1,
      paste(
        setdiff(
          unlist(strsplit(e_street_name,"")),
          liste_carac
        ), collapse = ", "
      ),
      "None"
    )
  )
```

Hope this helps!!